# Alert Dialogue Box in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

It is my understanding that Google Apps Script (GAS) has provided a popup dialogue box that corresponds to the alert dialogue box in client-side JS (See: http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/message-dialogs-in-apps-script/) In trying to get acquainted with this dialogue box, I have prepared the test code shown below:

Code.gs:

```
var validate=function() {
   Browser.msgBox('Hello, world!', Browser.Buttons.OK);  // See: http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/message-dialogs-in-apps-script/
}
function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('Test').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    }
```

index.html:

```
<div>
 <form>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="validate">
 </form>
</div>
```

When I click on the "Click Me" button, instead of seeing a popup dialogue box, nothing happens and an error is reported in the JS console complaining that "validate" is not defined.  Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing?  Thanks for any input.

```
 ... doug
```

Answer (score 2):

`Browser.msgBox()` runs from the server.  You probably already know that.  But you aren't calling the server.  Your `onclick` attribute needs to have a `google.script.run.serverFunctionName();` call in it.  Or, as shown below, put the `google.script.run` call in a separate function.

### HTML Code:

```
<div>
 <form>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="validate()">
 </form>
</div>

<script>
  window.validate = function() {
    google.script.run.validate();
  };
</script>
```

### Code.gs

```
function validate() {
  Logger.log('It ran!');
  Browser.msgBox('Hello, world!', Browser.Buttons.OK);  // See: http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/message-dialogs-in-apps-script/
}
function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('Test').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    }
```

Comment: note that there is no need to do this at all from clientside. just use alert/prompt etc.

Answer (score 0):

Browser methods are for uiApp, not for htmlApp. they run server-side and might not even work when called from clientside as a foogle.run function. it also will have sidewffects as it wont be modal to the client.

simply use the existing alert/prompt javascript functions available in the client side browser.

Comment: Thanks.  I ran tests.  It's clear that the client-side alert function will work. I was wrong in believing that it wouldn't.  However, it seems that I have a more basic problem.  Notice that in my original post I said that the JS console complained that "validate" was not defined.  I still have that problem.  Here is my current code:

Comment: Sorry, attempting to show the code posted my comment.  Too late to edit.  I'd really like to pass along my code.  You can probably imagine what it looks like.  Any ideas on why I'm getting the validate-not-defined error?  Thanks.

Comment: because validate is in the server not client. put it in the client js. Read and undestand well the differences between server (.gs) and client (.js) code before proceeding further.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks to everyone for all the help.  Yes, I definitely need to keep my head screwed on WRT what is server-side and what is client-side.  If anyone has anything I should read on that point, I'd love a link.  Thanks again.